# How to use angular-card

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, error-handling

I want to use im my angularJS project :  https://github.com/gavruk/angular-card/blob/master/src/card.js

but when i do everyhing like showed in documentation i get:

```
libraries.js:30369 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp.controllers due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angular-card due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-card' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Comment: Did you include the module in the application modules?

Comment: Your first mistake is that you're still trying to use AngularJS which is deprecated with only patch updates. Also, what @briosheje said, make sure you added to your `app.module` initialization.

Comment: after npm i angular-card i did angular.module('app', ['gavruk.card'])

Comment: @MladenSkrbic : sounds like your main module is `myApp` rather than `app`. You should add `gavruk.card` to the child module dependencies, in your case, from the error code, I would guess that your main module is `myApp`.

Comment: after npm install do i need to require it or add some script to index.html?